# Cannot play music with flutter sound plugin on Android Pie

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-mediaplayer, flutter-dependencies

I am using [Flutter Sound plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sound) to play music from a URL on Android. This worked without any problem on Android 8, but after updating to Android 9, the music from URL doesn't play anymore. I opened an issue for [the plugin](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/issues/51), but this seems to be some breaking change in the Android 9 itself.

Is there any change in Android 9 which would cause this?

I couldn't find anything obvious on [android 9 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all).

Here is the log output:

```
I/MediaPlayer(26707): Need to enable context aware info
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26707): native_setup
I/flutter (26707): error: Exception: Player already stopped.
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): constructor
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): setListener
V/MediaHTTPService(26707): MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@b2558b2): Cookies: null
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): prepare
V/MediaHTTPService(26707): makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@b993003
V/MediaHTTPService(26707): makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@b2558b2): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@b993003 Cookies: null
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeOut = 15000ms
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(26707): Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaHTTPConnection(26707): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out(26707): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): message received msg=300, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): Received SEC_MM_PLAYER_CONTEXT_AWARE
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
E/MediaPlayerNative(26707): error (1, -2147483648)
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): signal application thread
V/MediaPlayerNative(26707): prepare complete - status=1
E/FlutterSoundPlugin(26707): startPlayer() exception
E/flutter (26707): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: PlatformException(ERR_UNKNOWN, ERR_UNKNOWN, Prepare failed.: status=0x1)
E/flutter (26707): #0 FlutterSound.startPlayer (package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart:163:7)
E/flutter (26707):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Because of this, the MediaPlayer was not able to open the provided URL.

Options are to:

1. set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Use HTTPS

Solutions are explained here [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)